# Asynchronously check for Reachability on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, asynchronous, reachability

I'm new to developing on iOS and in Objective-C.

According to this technical note (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1693/_index.html), 
It is recommended to check for Reachability using async APIs on app startup, in order to prevent the app from being killed by the Watchdog.

I have looked at the samples + documentation here: [SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/SCNetworkReachabilityRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback)

This allows registering a callback that is asynchronously invoked when reachability state changes.

However, this does not solve the issue of detecting what the state is RIGHT NOW (the callback is only raised on changes to reachability state).

What is the preferred way of getting the reachability state flags ? is there an Async API for that ?

Comment: Are you sure that the async method does not report initial state?

Comment: @TomErikStøwer it only raises the callback when the state actually changes.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-detecting-network-changes-with-reachability--mobile-18299) which uses the Tony Million Reachability class.